# PHP array from database

Tags: php

In my database I got 3 rows. Product, quantity, and rate.

```
$rate = implode(",", $_POST["myrate"]);
```

This is the rate. Which means one row can be "rate1, rate2, rate3" and so on. But it's the same with product and quantity.

```
"product1, product2, product3"
"quantity1, quantity2, quantity3"
"rate1, rate2, rate3"
```

If I echo it out It'll be as above. But what I want is:

```
"product1, quantity1, rate1"
"product2, quantity2, rate2"
"product3, quantity3, rate3"
```

How is this possible?

https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery
That's the code I'm using. Have just added 2 fields and 2 rows.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','invoice-generator');

    //Output any connection error
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $capture_field_vals = "";
    if(isset($_POST["mytext"]) && is_array($_POST["mytext"])){
        $capture_field_vals = implode(",", $_POST["mytext"]); 
        $quantity = implode(",", $_POST["myquantity"]); 
        $rate = implode(",", $_POST["myrate"]); 
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }

    //MySqli Insert Query
    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO invoice_rows (product, quantity, rate) VALUES ('$capture_field_vals', '$quantity', '$rate')");

    if($insert_row){
        echo 'Success!';
    }else{
        echo "error2";
    }
?>
```

Comment: show your database table data (through figure) and the code what you tried? it's difficult to understand what you want and what you are trying to say?

Comment: Very strange database design... But you can certainly save the rows to variables, explode them into arrays and then iterate over them by means of a php loop.

Comment: why are you making a string as you can use direct arrays for required result.

Comment: Have now updated the question with a link

Comment: Do you really need to store your data like this.  You could simply store it in rows like  `"product1, quantity1, rate1"`,  `product1, quantity1, rate1"` etc. As there is no way you can get such combination if you store data the way you are storing now.

Comment: How? Updating with my PHP code

Comment: A simple loop through your POST array will accomplish what you're looking for.  Incidentally, if you intend on anyone ever using this, there's a lot wrong with the code you provided.

Comment: With a loop I'll get a lot of rows. But can you please show me how

Answer (score 1):

```
$quantity = array("q1","q2","q3","q4");
$product = array("p1","p2","p3","p4");
$rate = array("r1","r2","r3","r4");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($quantity); $i++) {
    $new_data[] = array($quantity[$i],$product[$i],$rate[$i]);
}
```

Get all of them in the loop and dump values into one array.

Comment: That's all what the OP got to do, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

If count of all variable are same than you can do like this

```
if (count($_POST["mytext"]) == count($_POST["myquantity"]) && count($_POST["myquantity"]) == count($_POST["myrate"])) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["mytext"]); $i++) {
    echo $_POST["mytext"][$i] . "," . $_POST["myquantity"][$i] . "," . $_POST["myrate"][$i] ."<br/>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Rate</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
//Lets say you have the data from your db in $results
<?php foreach($results as $result): ?>
<tr>   //loop one whole row
<td><?=$result['product']?></td>
<td><?=$result['quantity']?></td>
<td><?=$result['rate']?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>

This way you can show product,quantity and row for each id in your database table in one row...if that is what you want
```